# Outlook image error when pasting a range as a picture

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that emails a range as a picture via outlook. The problem is that the recipients are getting the outlook error "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location."

Anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xHTMLBody As String
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:F17")
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle: Rounded Corners 13").Visible = False

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Call createJpg(ActiveSheet.Name, xRg.Address, "DashboardFile")
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    xHTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
            & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
            & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'>" _
            '& "<br> "

    StrBody = "<br />" & "<b><FONT SIZE = 5><font color=red>Rates are subject to change 
    without notice</b></FONT SIZE = 5></font color=red>"
    
    With xOutMail
        .Subject = "Bench Mark Rates" & " " & Date
        .HTMLBody = xHTMLBody & StrBody
      .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue
        .To = "mcerrato@hotmail.com
        .cc = "mcerrato@loandepot.com"
        .Display
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle: Rounded Corners 13").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try so switch this two lines

**As is**

```
  .HTMLBody = xHTMLBody & StrBody
  .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue
```

**To be**

```
  .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue
  .HTMLBody = xHTMLBody & StrBody
```

Comment: It did not fix it.

Comment: You said that the recipients, get the error message! When you run the procedure see the image, correct? Did you try to put your address as a recipient to see if you see the image?

Comment: Yes of course, I am sending to my hotmail account and my corporate account. Both show the same result.

Comment: Try to remove ``cid:`` from the img tag